# Code folding group of lines inside a cell in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

Is there a way to fold code *inside a cell* in Jupyter Lab. The code folding in my notebooks works fine for loops, classes, methods but I'd like to fold sections of at will without creating a new section.

[image: Jupyter Lab]

I can do something similar in Mathematica with 'iconize/uniconize' and even in RStudio like they do [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst searching for a more elegant solution myself I came across your question; this is an example of a workaround I have been using:

Just define the code you want to call in a function and call the function straight after.

[Example code unfolded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pfr1.png)

[Example code folded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf0hq.png)

Edit:

```
if True:
    data1 = [1, 3, 4]
```

is another short option but it will not be very clear what it represents when the code is collapsed.

Comment: I sometimes do that too in order to break larger chunks of code but it's annoying because it introduces two new lines of code.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: In order to improve the quality of your answer, it is recommended, if possible, to not include links to code answering the question.